# Increase, decrease value in Input and don't show negative number

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make input form and its value can be increased and decreased by click +1 / -1 buttons and I have +5 / -5 button also.

When the value is 3 and click -5 button, the value become -2. 
But I don't want to show negative number. I want minimum number is always "0".  Even the result value is negative number.

How do I fix the code?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".plus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $this.siblings('input');
    var value = parseInt($input.val());

    if (value < 30) {
      value = value + 1;
    } else {
      value = 30;
    }

    $input.val(value);
  });


  $(".plus2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $this.siblings('input');
    var value = parseInt($input.val());

    if (value < 30) {
      value = value + 5;
    } else {
      value = 30;
    }

    $input.val(value);
  });


  $(".minus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $this.siblings('input');
    var value = parseInt($input.val());

    if (value > 0) {
      value = value - 1;
    } else {
      value = 0;
    }

    $input.val(value);
  });


  $(".minus2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $this.siblings('input');
    var value = parseInt($input.val());

    if (value > 0) {
      value = value - 5;
    } else {
      value = 0;
    }

    $input.val(value);
  });


});
```

```css
.change_qty {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2e748e;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.cursor_hover {
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change_qty {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2e748e;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.cursor_hover {
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-bottom:2em;text-align:center;">

  <div class="change_qty minus2 cursor_hover">&#45;5</div>
  <div class="change_qty minus cursor_hover">&#45;1</div>

  <input type="numeric" style="height:22px;width:40px;margin:0 .5em;text-align:center;" value="0">

  <div class="change_qty plus cursor_hover">&#43;1</div>
  <div class="change_qty plus2 cursor_hover">&#43;5</div>

</div>
```

This is what I tried here 
http://jsfiddle.net/a5ktensk/63/

Comment: `<input type="number"  min="0"`

Comment: Isn't this as simple as when changing the value, check to see if it's less than zero and if so, set it to zero?

Comment: You check if your input value is below 0, but you have to check if your result after calc is below 0.

Comment: Because I cannot post an answer, here is the answer I wanted to gave you `https://jsfiddle.net/exoj6yhL/`. There are 2 solutions for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the if statement should do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/a5ktensk/68/

```
if (value > 5) { 
    value = value - 5; 
} 
else { 
    value = 0; 
}
```

Another option would be.

```
value = value -5;
if(value < 0) {
    value = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works great :)